# Implementing timeout in async retry operations

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, retry-logic

I wrote an async method with retry logic. It works just fine, however recently I wanted to add a timeout **for each try** in case the operation takes too long.

```
public static async Task<Result> PerformAsync(Func<Task> Delegate,
    Func<Exception, bool> FailureCallback = null, int Timeout = 30000,
    int Delay = 1000, int Threshold = 10)
{
    if (Delegate == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(Delegate));
    }

    if (Threshold < 1)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(Threshold));
    }

    CancellationTokenSource Source = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken Token = Source.Token;

    bool IsSuccess = false;

    for (int Attempt = 0; Attempt <= Threshold && !Source.IsCancellationRequested;
        Attempt++)
    {
        try
        {
            await Delegate();

            Source.Cancel();

            IsSuccess = true;

            break;
        }

        catch (Exception E)
        {
            Exceptions.Add(E);

            if (FailureCallback != null)
            {
                bool IsCanceled =
                    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Func<bool>(() =>
                {
                    return !FailureCallback(E);
                }));

                if (IsCanceled)
                {
                    Source.Cancel();

                    IsSuccess = false;

                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        await Task.Delay(Delay);
    }

    return new Result(IsSuccess, new AggregateException(Exceptions));
}
```

I've been trying various solutions all over the web, but for whatever reason I've never managed to set timeout for each try individually.

I tried to do this using `Task.WhenAny()` with `Task.Delay(Timeout)`, but when I launch my program, `FailureCallback` is called only once and if another try fails, `FailureCallback` is not called.

Comment: As a side note, I suggest to take a look at this article: [Framework design guidelines - Capitalization Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions): *DO use camelCasing for parameter names.*!!

Comment: What would you like to happen in case of a timeout? To cancel the currently running task and wait for its cancellation to occur, or to leave it running, forget about it, and launch a new task that will be running concurrently with the old one?

Comment: Please use [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, lets start. First of all, the intended usage of a CancellationToken isn't to cancel locally a loop, that's a waste, a CancellationToken reserves some resources and in your case you can simply usea boolean.

```
bool IsSuccess = false;
bool IsCancelled = false;

for (int Attempt = 0; Attempt <= Threshold; Attempt++)
{

    try
    {
        await Delegate();
        IsSuccess = true;
        //You are breaking the for loop, no need to test the boolean
        //in the for conditions
        break;
    }

    catch (Exception E)
    {
        Exceptions.Add(E);

        if (FailureCallback != null)
        {
            IsCancelled = Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Func<bool>(() =>
            {
                    return !FailureCallback(E);
            }));

            //You are breaking the for loop, no need to test the boolean
            //in the for conditions

            if(IsCancelled)
                break;

        }
    }

    await Task.Delay(Delay);
}

//Here you have "IsSuccess" and "IsCancelled" to know what happened in the loop
//If IsCancelled is true the operation was cancelled, if IsSuccess is true
//the operation was success, if both are false the attempt surpased threshold.
```

Second, you must update your delegate to be cancellable, that's the real intended usage of `CancellationToken`, make your delegate to expect a `CancellationToken` and use it properly inside the function.

```
public static async Task<Result> PerformAsync(Func<CancellationToken, Task> Delegate, //..

//This is an example of the Delegate function
public Task MyDelegateImplemented(CancellationToken Token)
{

    //If you have a loop check if it's cancelled in each iteration
    while(true)
    {
        //Throw a TaskCanceledException if the cancellation has been requested
        Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        //Now you must propagate the token to any async function
        //that accepts it
        //Let's suppose you are downloading a web page

        HttpClient client;

        //...

        await client.SendAsync(message, Token)

    }

}
```

Finally, now that your task is cancellable you can implement the timeout like this:

```
//This is the "try" in your loop
try
{
    var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    var call = Delegate(tokenSource.Token);
    var delay = Task.Delay(timeout, tokenSource.Token);

    var finishedTask = await Task.WaitAny(new Task[]{ call, delay });

    //Here call has finished or delay has finished, one will
    //still be running so you need to cancel it

    tokenSource.Cancel();
    tokenSource.Dispose();

    //WaitAny will return the task index that has finished
    //so if it's 0 is the call to your function, else it's the timeout

    if(finishedTask == 0)
    {
        IsSuccess = true;
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        //Task has timed out, handle the retry as you need.
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! However, I have some questions: 1. What's the purpose of the while loop in your delegate example? 2. I still don't get it, maybe I haven't made it clear enough. There is "Task has timed out, handle the retry as you need." in your code, but it's not inside any loop. I need timeout for each try. E.g. First try, times out in 30 seconds. Try again, time out in 30 seconds. Third try, etc.

Comment: You need to read all the comments in the code as they explain what you ask. 1-It's an example as it states, it shows you how to use the token in a loop in case you have one and how to properly check for cancellation.2-as the comment says that `try` is the `try` inside your `for` loop

Comment: Corrected a bug, the break in the try must be only executed if it was success.